# Operator curl and gradient

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces, mathematical-physics

Operator curl $\nabla$  x$(\cdot)$ (x is cross product) working on  a $ C^1$ vector field and operator gradient $\nabla(\cdot)$ working on scalar fields. And results of these operators is vector field.
Is there any object (member) of kernel of curl in the images of gradient? (Any of members of kernel  of curl is in the image of gradient is that true?)
and is there any object (member) of images of gradient in the kernel of curl? (Any of members of image of gradient is in the kernel of curl is that true?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\text{curl}(\text{grad}\,f) = \mathbf 0$ for any function with continuous second-order partial derivatives. *Provided* we're in a simply connected region in space, then it is true that if $\text{curl}\,\mathbf F = \mathbf 0$, we have $F = \text{grad}\,f$. (Actually, something a bit weaker holds: You need the first cohomology $H^1(X,\mathbb R)$ to vanish; if $X$ is simply connected, this happens.)

Comment: so for the first question the answer is yes.right?How about the second one?I cant recognize these 2 questions

Comment: Your question is phrased, I think, in the sense of "is some?" I'm telling you the answer is *always* for your second question and *most of the time* for your first.

Comment: can you tell me why 'most of the times' for  the first?what's the problem?

Comment: That was in my answer. You need the region to be simply connected ... i.e., no "$1$-dimensional holes." For example removing the $z$-axis from $\Bbb R^3$ will give us the standard vector field $\frac1{x^2+y^2}(-y\mathbf i + x\mathbf j)$, which has curl $=\mathbf 0$ but is not conservative, i.e., not a gradient.